# Replace space characters in paths with what?

Tags: java, path, cygwin

I start bash from Java app and I have in my path for command which executes inside bash spaces
( example cd /Documents and Settings/test ), I run command with Process Builder but it doesn't work when path have spaces. I try to replace spaces with %20 but not help. What to do ?

Comment: You need to run a command which works from the bash prompt. e.g. cd /Document and Settings/ won't. Try `cd C:Documents\ and\ Settings` which does.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Please post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either encapsulate the full path in quotion marks like this:

```
String quoted = "\"" + pathString + "\"";
```

or, as you use bash, escape the spaces:

```
String escaped = pathString.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

Both should work as an argument for your `cd` command.

Answer (score 4):

encapsulate the whole path between quotations.

```
cd "/Documents and Settings/test"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using %20 here is nonsense, it's no URL. Use String[] or List[] instead of String and then you can leave the spaces as they are, there's no more cmd line args splitting there.

So you could use

```
"cd", "/Documents and Settings/test"
```

however, this make no sense as a shell command. You can't change the working dir of Java this way, as you're starting a new process. You may want to write a shell script (batch file) and invoke it from Java.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that running the `cd` command using `Process` has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run a command which works from the bash prompt. e.g. cd /Document and Settings/ won't. Try `cd C:Documents\ and\ Settings` which does.

NOTE: bash requires you use a C: at the start to access this folder. Using just / at the start will give you cygwin's a virtual root.