# Why is my text getting tokenised with solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have been scratching my head for over a day now trying to fix this. This is the definition of field type in schema.xml

```
    <fieldType name="text_plain" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I have indexed, among others, a field like "Unity is great" (without double quotes). If I search "Unity", I do get the result. If I search "Unity ", I get all results that are indexed (I believe this is because the whitespace got indexed). If I search "Unity i", I get nothing. I am trying to search with a query like this: fieldName: nameParam*, where nameParam is the search query parameter and fieldName is the field that has been indexed.

What I want is to get the results for the exact phrase, like when I search with query "Unity i", I want just one result.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the problem after reading this: [Replace space characters in paths with what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746953/replace-space-characters-in-paths-with-what)

all I had to do was escape spaces when querying.